# Servicing Stack Update (SSU) for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I want to solve CBS Error by I got from

```
sfc /scannow
```

gives me `CBS.log` with Error `CBS_E_NEW_SERVICING_STACK_REQUIRED`

I tried to manually install KB5004378 but everytime it fails with *"This update is not applicable to your computer.*"

How can I update Servicing Stack v6.1.7601.24554?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to manually install KB5004378 but everytime it failed with "The update is not suitable for your computer."

KB5004378 requires a Extended Security Updates (ESU) subscription. To put it simply, in order to install either update, you need a Windows 7 ESU Multiple Activation Key (MAK).

Source: [Obtaining Extended Security Updates for eligible Windows devices](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/obtaining-extended-security-updates-for-eligible-windows-devices/ba-p/1167091)

> Installing MAK keys adds the ability to receive ESU. It doesn't replace the current product activation key (for example, OEM, KMS), nor does it reactivate the system. Organizations will have to install a new MAK key for every year that they deploy ESU.

Source: [How can organizations install and activate the Windows 7 ESU MAK key?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-7-eos-faq/windows-7-extended-security-updates-faq#how-can-organizations-install-and-activate-the-windows-7-esu-mak-key-)

The last SSU update that you can install without a ESU subscription is KB4536952

Answer (score 0):

By installing [BypassESU-v11](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2019/12/07/windows-7-erweiterte-sicherheitsupdates-esu-erhalten-wird-moeglich-sein) finally was able to install KB5004378 Servicing Stack v6.1.7601.24554

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\BypassESU-v11

C:\BypassESU-v11>LiveOS-Setup.cmd

____________________________________________________________

Installing ESU Suppressor . . .


____________________________________________________________

Installing WU ESU Patcher . . .


adding "C:\Windows\WuEsu"

adding "C:\Windows\System32\sle.dll"

adding schedule task "Patch WU ESU"

running schedule task "Patch WU ESU"

____________________________________________________________

Installing .NET 4 ESU Bypass . . .


adding files...

C:\Windows\System32\
ActionCenter.dll.3.Manifest
perfmon.exe.3.Manifest
pnidui.dll.3.Manifest
timedate.cpl.3.Manifest
msiexec.exe.manifest
msislc.dll
slcmsi.dll

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
ActionCenter.dll.3.Manifest
perfmon.exe.3.Manifest
pnidui.dll.3.Manifest
timedate.cpl.3.Manifest
msiexec.exe.manifest
msislc.dll
slcmsi.dll

adding PreferExternalManifest registry...

Done.
```

[image]